# How to plot AM,PM labels in HighChart?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I am using High charts to plot a graph.Graph type is column range.I am plotting 24 hour in y axis and days in x axis.I want to show Labels in y axis as AM,Noon,PM.Please help

Below code not working.Time plotted in UTC

```
var yourLabels = {
    0: 'AM',   
    10: 'Noon',
    20: 'PM'
};

labels: {
            formatter: function() {
            return yourLabels[this.value];
          }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to have some live demo to work with. However, I would use [`tickPositions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions) to create ticks in a proper places, something like this:

```
yAxis: {
     tickPositions: [0, 10, 20],
     showFirstLabel: true,
     showLastLabel: true,
     labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return yourLabels[this.value];
        }
     }
}
```